# Combination yii 1 and codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, yii, view, grid

I have searched for a good grid view codeigniter but I could not find it.
 Gride view framework Yii 1 is very flexible, is it possible
Use Grid view yii in codeigniter 2.2?

Comment: Why not use bootstrap 3 with codeigniter very easy to use.

Comment: can you more explain?

Comment: i known bootstrap 3?

Comment: you can use other jquery plugin like [datatable](http://datatables.net) , [jqgrid](http://jqgrid.com) etc